# Как использовать BoxLayout без ориентаций?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, layout

Почему используя вертикальную ориентацию BoxLayout я могу двигать кнопку только по горизонтали, а используя горизонтальную - только по вертикали?
Например:

```
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
    KV = '''
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDRaisedButton:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .3,'center_y': .5}
    '''
    class FindWord(MDApp):
        def build(self):
            return Builder.load_string(KV)
    FindWord().run()
```

**Горизонтальная ориентация, также ориентация по умолчанию:**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
KV = '''
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        MDRaisedButton:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .3,'center_y': .5}
'''
class FindWord(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
FindWord().run()
```

Как свободно перемещать виджеты по обеим осям? Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы располагать виджеты где угодно нужно использовать не BoxLayout, а FloatLayout разница лишь в том, что нужно указывать где именно будет расположен виджет.

Пример кода:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = FloatLayout(size=(300, 300))
        button = Button(
            text='Hello world',
            size_hint=(.5, .25),
            pos=(20, 20))
        
        #можно установить адаптивное расположение через pos_hint
        button1 = Button(
            text='Hello world2',
            size_hint=(.5, .25),
            pos_hint={'x': .3, 'y': .4})

        layout.add_widget(button)
        layout.add_widget(button1)

        return layout


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]